# Doctrine Single Table Inheritance preserving findAll

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a strong issue while trying to play with Doctrine Single Table Inheritance.

I have a `Division` entity, which represents geographic divisions (cities, counties, countries, regions, or any country-specific administrative division). For my application needs, I need to specifically identify cities with a `City` entity. Cities being the widely shared administrative areas in the world, it makes sense in my opinion.

Here is what I *basically* want:

```
class Division {
    /** @var boolean */
    protected $city;
}
```

```
class City extends Division {
    /** @var boolean */
    protected $city = true;
}
```

Both being Doctrine entities sharing the same table.

Using the repositories, I want to be able to get this behaviour:

```
// return counties, regions, AND cities but all mapped to Division class
$divisionsRepositories->findAll();

// return only cities, mapped to City class
$citiesRepositories->findAll();

// if id #12 is a division with $city = false, returns null
$citiesRepositories->find(12);

// persist to divisions table a row with city = 1
$citiesRepositories->persist(new City("Paris"));
```

I've played a lot with discriminators and couldn't find a way to get this result as the Discriminator forces me to make a unique choice for Division entity (and so queries always get a `city IN ('0')`). I even tried to create a "loadClassMetadata" Event Listener to override metadata but it breaks a lot of stuff.

In case of the question "why" is asked: typehinting, more accurate related entities relations, specific repository (and so better DI)... lots of reasons !

Any idea on how to reproduce this with Doctrine ? It looks so simple that it makes me crazy !

[EDIT]
Here is (one of) the discriminatorMap I've tried as requested in comments:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="divisions")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="city", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     0 = "Division",
 *     1 = "Division",
 *     1 = "City"
 * })
 */
abstract class AbstractDivision
```

Comment: How is your Discriminator Map? Can you show us?

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes: post edited with an example

Comment: I'm writing a answer, but.. Why you need to return all as `Division` instance if a `City` is always a `Division` itself?

Comment: Yes, I don't really care to have one `City` object in the middle of `Division` results, as City is itself a Division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do that. We have `@DiscriminatorMap` explanation in [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-discriminatormap):

> The key on DiscriminatorMap is the database value and values are the classes.

So if you set two Classes to the database value, how doctrine will return a row that has the column `city=1` as a City or as a Division?

How doctrine works:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="divisions")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="city", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     0 = "Division",
 *     1 = "City"
 * })
 */
abstract class Division

// return Division and it subclasses but all mapped to their repectives classes
$divisionsRepositories->findAll();

// return only cities, mapped to City class
$citiesRepositories->findAll();

// if id #12 is a Division instance (city = false), returns null
$citiesRepositories->find(12);

// persist to divisions table a row with city = 1
$citiesRepositories->persist(new City("Paris"));
```

So almost every thing works like you expected. The first case, `$divisionsRepositories->findAll()` it's the only problem here. But if you look carefully isn't because:

```
//if $divisions returns for instance an array [City, Division]
$divisions = $divisionsRepositories->findAll();

// City instance
$city =  $division[0];

// Division instance
$division = $division[1];

echo $city instanceof City; // true, outputs 1
echo $city instanceof Division; // true, outputs also 1

echo $division instanceof City; // false, outputs empty
echo $division instanceof Division; // true, outputs 1
```

**Edit**

The only difference I've found about your problem and mine jobs about it: it's I didn't use a abstract class. So, Division would have all annotations and AbstractdDivision would be removed.

About filter in query builder by instances, returns only City or Division. You should add 'INSTANCE OF' like below:

```
 //$qb as a QueryBuilder instance, to returns only instances of City
 $qb->from('\ApiBundle\Entity\Geography\Division','d');
 $qb->andWhere('d INSTANCE OF \ApiBundle\Entity\Geography\City');
```

Comment: To be honest, the findAll method was an example. My main concern is the whole ORM usage : for example, any QueryBuilder built from createQueryBuilder method from the Division repository have the `city IN ('0')` where condition automatically added though, so it's pretty unusable "as it". Any attempt to add `->where('d.city = 0')` will lead to a `Class ApiBundle\\Entity\\Geography\\Division has no field or association named city` as the field is not really mapped.

Comment: I think that the "forget about discriminator and create your extended version of the EntityRepository" is probably the best choice. It would also mean in my case creating my own factory method to create the repository as I'm using Symfony and declaring my repositories as services !

Comment: I see. This is because city is not a mapped column and you can't do that once it is a discriminator, it's like a metadata.

Comment: + you're wrong, findAll() returns only `Division` objects -_-'

Comment: I've updated the answer. May be the reason you only get Division objects.

Comment: OMG you made it ;). What led me to this wrong abstract class choice was Doctrine itself, can't remember why but I got an error saying it should be abstract when I tried to do something similar ! Here is a working POC : https://github.com/philippecarle/doctrine-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You need to define at least one [repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) for the child entity and overwrite the findAll and find methods in order to achieve what you described above.

Comment: That was my (last) thought but I think I need to overwrite createQueryBuilder, find, findBy, findAll, ... and even __call ! This is what I try to avoid to be honest, it wouldn't worth the effort...

Comment: Based on the requirement you provided in your question I can only see the need to overwrite find and findAll for the city's repo. But of course if findBy is another fetcher that your going to need, then yes, you need to cover that as well. I'm not sure why you need to manipulate __call and createQueryBuilder but certainly it sounds like you are not in the right approach. There is Notting wrong with have a single entity covering a single table and have a flag to identify its nature :)

Comment: Sure, I agree with what you say but thing is that the discriminator feature would just perfectly match my need if only it would allow to define a "default" behaviour for a "main" entity (aka "just give me my whole table Doctrine please, forget about discrimination for this entity only" ;) ).

Comment: @Ali, I don't think it's necessary do that. Just update your DiscriminatorMap like I did in my answer and everything should work like expected.

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes, like the approach but still am not %100 about the added value of dividing the entity in two in the given example. I'm sure Philippe has some good reason (just type-hinting can be provided at the usage point), otherwise still I would vote for the simplicity:)